# "talk to" vs "talk with"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any difference between “talk to someone” and “talk with someone”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/is-there-any-difference-between-talk-to-someone-and-talk-with-someone)

Should I say

> I talked to Bob.

or

> I talked with Bob.