# 'Meeting us' or 'meeting with us'?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions, transitivity

What is the difference between meeting with someone or meeting someone?

For example when I would like to ask someone if he is happy to meet with me and my friend for the first time, how should I ask? "If you are up to meeting us" or "if you are up to meeting with us"?

I tried to google this and use the search, but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: What did the dictionary say?

Comment: You may care to look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/866/speak-to-vs-speak-with) or [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/is-there-any-difference-between-talk-to-someone-and-talk-with-someone).

Comment: Or you may care to ask [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) on 
**English Language Learners**.

Answer (score 7):

Typically, if you "meet with someone," you already know the person, and you are setting up an arranged time to talk.

To "meet someone" usually means to greet them for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are acceptable ways to say it, but depending on where one's from, one of them will sound more correct and natural. As an American I would say that the first one is more common/natural/brief.

Answer (score 0):

I think
'Meet' is a verb meaning to come into the presence or company of someone by chance or arrangement. E.g. I met an old friend in the train.
'Meet with' is a phrasal verb.
It means:
1.To come across; encounter 
2.To meet with opposition.
3.To experience; undergo; receive:
E.g.,The visitors met with courtesy during their stay.
4.To join, as for conference or instruction:
E.g.,I met with her an hour a day until we solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

> What is the difference between meeting with someone or meeting
>   someone?

"Meeting with", is American English. That is the difference. Using the word *with*, is not really necessary. It does not add any, extra meaning. It's superfluous. It is surplus to requirements. An unnecessary, added extra.