# "Meet" a friend or "meet with" a friend?

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

Is there any difference in usage?

**Meet** a friend or **meet with** a friend.

> I'm **meeting** my friend today.
>
> I sometimes **meet with** my friends.

Comment: You could have a look [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/is-there-any-difference-between-talk-to-someone-and-talk-with-someone/1030#1030) or [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/866/speak-to-vs-speak-with).

Comment: Thank you but it's  not what I ask about.  Is it possible to use the expression  meet with friends or I must only say  meet friends?

Comment: If you want to use the latest neologism then you "meet up with" a friend and get two redundant words for the price of one.

Comment: Thanks for deleting the question. I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) and try to ask specific questions. It is not easy to learn and understand how English words work unless you spend a lot of time reading various sources such as newspaper, magazine, etc. ELL will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you . I think I better read,speak and understand than translate. It is really difficult because of culture gap.

Answer (score 7):

Compare...

> 1: *I sometimes meet my ex-wife in the park*
>    2: *I sometimes meet with my ex-wife in the park*

The default meaning of #1 is that I *encounter* her (probably accidentally) when I go to the park, whereas for #2 it's that I meet up with her *by arrangement* from time to time.

This is because *to meet* on its own has a broad range of possible meanings. But if you include the preposition *(to meet **with**)*, this puts more focus on the idea that you *spent time **with*** the other person, rather than briefly encountered them.

If you're talking about a *future* meeting, it's probably planned in advance anyway, and you'll be expecting to do more than simply nod to each other in passing. So in that context there's really not much to choose between the two.

Comment: As always, great answer

Comment: Thank you very much. The matter is that I was told  that any time I want to mention that I'm  going to see my friends I should say I'm going to meet my friends without using of with. I completely  lost myself in all these:))

Comment: @Marita: The distinction above doesn't provide a hard-and-fast rule for *all* contexts. But in your example *I sometimes meet [with] my friends* I think with no further context, most native speakers would expect the preposition to be present (because you probably don't just *encounter* them, you *spend time with* them). Consequently, if you *don't* include ***with***, your audience may be inclined to assume a less likely meaning (that you mainly interact with your friends online, say, and only occasionally meet them "in the flesh").

Comment: Now I see the difference.I think some non-native teachers tend  to find kind of a hard-and-fast rule for their students. But any language is flexible and there's no possibility to put it into some framework.

Comment: "I am going to meet my friends" might mean to go somewhere and wait for your friend.

Comment: @Marita: There are many contexts where if someone uses a less common form, we automatically assume this is because they intend a less common *meaning*. In this case, the default meaning of *meet [someone]* is just *encounter, come across [him]*, leaving *meet with him* free to be assigned a different meaning. If we have a different indirect object, such as *meet **with his approval***, the verb takes on yet another meaning.

Answer (score 4):

For me, *meet with* (apart from the metaphoric *meet with approval/disaster*) is a neologism that I encountered in American sources before I ever met it in Britain.

I would not talk about *meeting with my friends* whether the meeting was planned or not. If I spoke of *meeting with someone* I would imply a more or less formal meeting, in a context of work or something like it.

Comment: That's interesting. I certainly recognize that there's something *very slightly* unnatural about *meeting **with** one's friends* (because of the associations with holding *formal* meetings). Maybe you're right that it's essentially an Americanism. But I think I also find it easier to "tolerate" because it puts me in mind of *meeting **up** with one's friends* (which has always been perfectly natural to me, and always implies "by arrangement").

Comment: _Meet up with_ is another Americanism, now widespread in Britain, which I have resisted.

Comment: Tsk. I always took you for a committed "descriptive linguist" who just happened to have a fine ear for regional differences. I'm now starting to suspect you might be a closet "nationalist" - at a time when we're all supposed to be discarding our local affiliations and signing up to become good Europeans! :)

Comment: I am a committed descriptivist. But I'm often more selective in my own speech: I just try and avoid forcing my preferences on others. _Meet up with_ always struck me as a wordy neologism, irrespective of its origin.

Comment: Me, I still try ***to*** avoid forcing my preferences on others! I went to a Comprehensive rather than a *Grammar school*, and that was probably the only aspect of grammar our English teacher bothered with (it's certainly about the only thing I *remember!* :)

Comment: Funnily enough, I noticed that _and_ as I wrote it, and wondered if it would elicit a reaction. It's how I speak, so I feel no need to edit it because some people have an arbitrary objection to it.

Comment: I should admit I was being a bit titchy (tongue-in-cheeky) there. I do remember the teacher telling us that, but I'm pretty sure even as a 12-year-old I thought it was pedantic/prescriptive tosh (though I probably didn't have those p-words at my fingertips then). In our context here I use either without giving it any thought. Obviously there are other contexts *(We tried **to** open the door, but it was locked)* where I trust I can be 100% certain we and all other competent speakers will always get it right. But mostly both versions are fine by me, and I don't see any "right/wrong" issue.