# The difference between "talk to" or "talk with "

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could please help me to figure out the difference between *talk to* or *talk with* someone? 
Thanks a lot for help))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between "talk to someone" and "talk with someone"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1029/is-there-any-difference-between-talk-to-someone-and-talk-with-someone) (itself closed as a duplicate of [“Speak to” vs. “Speak with”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/866/speak-to-vs-speak-with)).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is rarely a difference. Talk with does imply that both people are engaging in conversation. In some specific cases talk to may be more correct if the object/person being spoken to isn't sentient or responding.

I can give my phone a voice command; in that case, I would say I am talking to my phone but the phone isn't really having a conversation with me, so I wouldn't say I am talking with my phone.

Comment: You say there really isn't a difference, yet you give a difference in your final statement.

Comment: @michael_timofeev You're right. There isn't a difference in most situations. I offered a rare situation where there is a difference. Perhaps I should edit.